# Google Maps API v3: DirectionsLeg comparable?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As we all know, Java compares `String` with `objA.equals.(objB)`
I found out, that this is possible for `LatLng`, too.

My question now: Is that also possible for `DirectionLegs`?

I have two different routes, but they are equal in one Leg. My attempt to do that has no success, so i am not sure if its because of my code or because of the fact, Legs are not comparable.

Comment: you may create an array of the latLng's defined for the steps of the leg, this array should be comparable.

Comment: I also mentioned this, but this includes legs, which have the same origin and destination, but another track to drive.

Comment: Do you have example routes that have a common leg that you would like to detect?